# What's the output of the following code?

Tags: c++, struct

This code was published in http://accu.org/index.php/cvujournal, Issue July 2013.
I couldn't comprehend the output, any explanation would be helphful

```
#include <iostream>
int x;

struct i
{
    i() { 
        x = 0;
        std::cout << "--C1\n";
    }

    i(int i) {
        x = i;
        std::cout << "--C2\n";
    }
};

class l
{
public:
    l(int i) : x(i) {}

    void load() {
        i(x);
    }

private:
    int x;
};

int main()
{
    l l(42);
    l.load();
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
--C1
0
```

I was expecting:

```
--C2
42
```

Any Explanation ?

Comment: `void load() { i y(x); }` outputs what you were expecting.

Comment: Or, more simply, `i{x};`

Comment: @chris That only works for C++11, right?

Comment: @Derek, Yes, it's uniform initialization.

Answer (score 20):

`i(x);` is equivalent to `i x;`, with a redundant pair of parentheses thrown in. It declares a variable named `x` of type `i`, default-initialized; it does not create a temporary instance of `i` with `x` as the constructor's parameter. See also: [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)